# SQLSyntaxErrorException - ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

In my java code, i am trying to perform insert operation but for some reasons i am getting `SQLSyntaxErrorException` . I am not getting the reason behind it though i tried. Below is my code.

```
Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(
            "insert into TABLE_DIMENSION (DIMESNION_ID, DIMENSION_CODE, TABLE_CODE, TABLE_IND, CREATE_TIME, "
            + "CREATE_PLACE, CHG_DT, CHG_WARDANT) "
            + " (select TABLE_DIMENSION_SEQ.nextval, d.name,:dimensionCode, 0, :time, :place, :date, :wardant from table_master d where d.name in (:table_dimension_ids)) ");
        nativeQuery.setParameter("date", new Date());
        nativeQuery.setParameter("table_dimension_ids", tableDimensionList);
        nativeQuery.setParameter("dimensionCode", dimensionCode);
        nativeQuery.setParameter("wardant", wardant);
        number = nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Please guide.

Comment: The SQL looks OK apart from the redundant brackets around the `select`. Does `TABLE_DIMENSION` really have a column called `DIMESNION_ID`? (Though an invalid column name would give a different error message.)

Comment: *"Please guide"* Here is some guidance: Google it: [`ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here`](https://www.google.com/search?q=ORA-02287%3A+sequence+number+not+allowed+here). You will then find good help.

Comment: @Andreas : Googling i have been doing since years. As there was no relevant question resembling to mine and i somewhere felt my code was right and not working i landed up asking the question !

Comment: I do agree that we should do our efforts before we post question and i had done mine. I didnt blantly ask for help. It was a problem to be resolved which i felt the expertise from stackoverflow can help and it did. You may refer to my accepted answer :)

Comment: You efforts should have brought you [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287), and then your question wouldn't be needed, because you'd have learned that you cannot use sequence *"in a sub-query"*.

Answer (score 2):

You told your query that you will use **6 parameters** but you set just **4 parameters**, you are missing to put `:place` and `:time` in the parameters like the others, so you have to use :

```
nativeQuery.setParameter("place", place);
nativeQuery.setParameter("time", time);
```

before you execute your query, else you have to remove it from your query

Comment: `:time` is also missing, not that either has anything to do with the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should skip `()`:

```
insert into TABLE_DIMENSION 
       (DIMESNION_ID, DIMENSION_CODE, TABLE_CODE, TABLE_IND
       , CREATE_TIME, CREATE_PLACE, CHG_DT, CHG_WARDANT)
select TABLE_DIMENSION_SEQ.nextval, d.name,:dimensionCode, 0
       , :time, :place, :date, :wardant 
from table_master d 
where d.name in (:table_dimension_ids)
```